# How can I adapt an array loop to this ios Push Notification function that currently accepts / sends to a SINGLE ios Device token?

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on building push notification routine for an iOS app I've built and successfully launched and have notification for a SINGLE device token working fine with the following code, but I'd like to instead have the notification sent to MULTIPLE device tokens (I would pull these from a mySQL database and pass that array to the PHP page that handles the Push Notification process)...

Heres the code I am using now for single device Token test:

```
<?php
// Message to send
$message = 'Test Push Notification message sent at '. date('H:i');

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';  // DADS device

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certfile);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);



// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx); 


if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'badge' => 1,
    'sound' => 'default'
);


// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    echo $result ;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp); return $response;
?>
```

Since this is one of my first real experiences with php (I deal daily with AS3, javascript, some and some legacy VBscript/classic ASP), I played around with PHP-based array looping and was able to do this very basic routine... my goal is to add this to the aforementioned code to use a SINGLE connection to the push notification server to send a single message to ALL the device tokens:

```
// START WITH A COMMA SEPARATED STRING OF VALUES AND TURN IT INTO AN ARRAY...
$myArr = 'test1, test2, test3, test4, test5';
$myList = explode(", ",$myArr);


// HEAVY LIFTING HANDLED HERE... A FUNCTION THAT LOOPS THROUGH ARRAY, AND SHOWS THE VALUE AND THE LENGTH OF THE VALUE
function doArrayListing($funcList){
    foreach ($funcList as $value) {
        print_r($value . "  " . strlen($value) ."\n");
    }
}

// CALL THE FUNCTION AND PASS THE ARRAY TO IT...
doArrayListing($myList);
```

so in a nutshell, Im trying to use something similar to loop through the array of device tokens, send the message and validate /read the response after each OR after ALL are done.

My plan 'B' is to do a process that will just send the message to a SINGLE device token, then wait x seconds before calling it again, but if I have 300 device tokens, for example, that could take a long time to send to all users... not to mention I dont know if I would be able to extend the timeout for the php page / process.

Im also looking into the apns feedback service because from my research, it sounds like if Im sending to a list of device tokens, and one of them is invalid or no longer registered with the apns, then the connection is dropped and it just dies... so I would be running a process beforehand that removes any invalid device tokens from my database.

Thanks for any help / guidance anyone can provide on this!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might come across this, the answer seems to be as simple as modifying it to do multiple $fwrites...

```
foreach ($myDevicesArray as $deviceToken) {

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    echo $result ;
};
```

... so basically, I have my array of device tokens, and I iterate over that array, building the binary notification, then sending to server, then print_r'ing the result.

Comment: One note: say you have 10 device tokens, but the 7th is invalid (i.e. the user uninstalled app, for example)... when you send out the notifications each will go out successfully UNTIL that 7th one.  the response / result may show as successful, but since its invalid as a token, apns will drop the connection to the server and tokens 8 through 10 wont be sent at all...

So I guess this means I have to use the apns feedback service to FIRST check the status of all my device tokens??? Im worried about how long that process takes.   having it just DROP the connection really really sucks.